# MVC jQuery Scroll to Loaded Partial View

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to use force jQuery using the Easing plugin to scroll down to a loaded partial view?

Currently I have a view which contains a search form, when a user enters criteria and submits the form a partial view is loaded below with search results.

At present the user can click either a Results hyperlink and the page will scroll down to the respective area or the user can click the Search hyperlink and the page will scroll back upwards accordingly.

I would like the page to actively scroll down as soon as the partial view (results) is loaded, as it makes sense for the user to see what they've search for.

**HTML**

```
<li class="page-scroll"><a href=#search>Search</a></li>
<li class="page-scroll"><a href=#results>Results</a></li>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
         var $anchor = $(this);
         $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
         }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
         event.preventDefault();
     });
 });
```

**View**

```
@{
    if (show)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/Results.cshtml");
    }
}
```

**Partial View**

```
<section id="results">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2>Results</h2>
                <hr class="star-primary">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Postcode</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Search_DataTable)
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: show the code where you load partial view

Comment: Please see the View and Partial View code, thank you.

Comment: why don't you load the partial with an ajax call?  That way there is no page submit and the page shouldn't move at all from where they are